# Web3 socket with options doesn't work

Tags: web3js, bsc, websocket

I'm trying to set some options in my wss connection but that seems don't have any effect using the moralis endpoint to connect in BSC

I tried to keep the connection but that's dropped yet

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const OPT = {
    keepalive: true,  
}

let provider = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(this.endpoint),null,OPT)
```

Comment: Hi kraune! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/include_package-core.html#configuration the options parameters should be next to the endpoint in the WebsocketProvider constructor, no the Web3.

Comment: Great! It will be nice if you can add the resulting line as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.